# MultiValueDictKeyError at /signup/ "'username'" in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

i created a signup page which creates users in django admin
this is how my signup.html looks alike

```
<h1>signup</h1>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}">

  username:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="username" >
  <br/>
 passwod:

 <br/>

  <input type="password" name="password1" >
  <br/>
confirm passwod:
<br/>

  <input type="password" name="passwod2" >
  <br/>

  <input type="submit"  value="signup">


</form>
```

and this is how i routed using my url to views:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
import accounts.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^signup/', accounts.views.signup, name='signup'),
```

and here is my views section:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template import RequestContext
# Create your views here.
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        User.objects.create_user(request.POST.get('username') , password=request.POST.get('password1')
        return render (request,'accounts/signup.html')

   else:
        return render (request,'accounts/signup.html')
```

but when i tried to run  the server and enter those details regarding username and password while submitting iam getting an error called MultiValueDictKeyError

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /signup/

"'username'"

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/
Django Version:     1.11.1
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

"'username'"

Exception Location:     C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 85
Python Executable:  C:\Python35\python.exe
Python Version:     3.5.3
Python Path:    

['D:\\python programs\\reddit\\redditclone',
 'C:\\Python35\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Python35\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python35\\lib',
 'C:\\Python35',
 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Server time:    Wed, 1 Nov 2017 04:05:10 +0000
```

any kind of help is appreciated 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that error because you havent mentioned the username attribute for the database which django expects to get to put the username in the username column of the User Table

so use this

```
User.objects.create(username=request.POST.get('username') , email=request.POST.get('email'),password=request.POST.get('password1'))
```

Comment: sir   i have did what you said me to do but after adding that line now iam getting a different error as return render (request,'accounts/signup.html')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax which is on line7 of my views.py

Comment: you need to close the bracket in the previous line, after the password thing, will edit my ans

Comment: @Exprator Do we need to specify username=request.POST.get('username'), because  create_user accepts username as first argument , email as second and password as third.  So User.objects.create_user(request.POST.get('username') , password=request.POST.get('password1') enough?

Comment: its a both way around, as he has mentioned password i told him to put username as django wont be able to differentiate which is what as one column name is given, else as you said it will work too. :)

Comment: the problem has been solved but when i submit iam getting an another error called ValueError at /signup/

The given username must be set ,thanks for your earlier response

Comment: @Exprator thanks a lot for tying to solve my issue but after replacing the edited line ,i saved it and tied to submit and now this time i got another different error called(IntegrityError at /signup/

NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.password) once agian i thank you for trying to solve this issue

Comment: you are not getting the password POSTED thus the error, try to check whether you are taking the right input and passing it to the backend, try to print the password to see if you get a value

Comment: i have rechecked everything regarding form as well as input section

Answer (score 1):

You are only using values given by the user. You have to give a default value if the user doesn't give any values.

the structure of request is like... `request.POST.get(<key>, <default>)`
you have to give a default value `username=request.POST.get("username", "default user")`